# What was Rasmus Lerdorf's first PHP website looks like

Tags: php

I've been reading about PHP history and wondering what was Rasmus Lerdorf's website looks like at that time.

> Originally used for tracking visits to his online resume, he named the
>   suite of scripts "Personal Home Page Tools," more frequently
>   referenced as "PHP Tools."

http://php.net/manual/en/history.php.php

I've been searching about this for a while but still couldn't find it. Therefore, I would appreciate if you could provide me the image or original link of his online resume at that time.

Comment: i was about to hit the flag button, but later realized, i also want to know the answer. :)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.infosystems.www.authoring.cgi/PyJ25gZ6z7A/M9FkTUVDfcwJ

Comment: @SebastianBrosch, is this the one?

http://www.io.org/~rasmus